# Sharepoint task list include ID number in email sent?

Tags: sharepoint-online, id

I have a sharepoint task list linked to a Teams site.

The task list sends an email everytime the assigned to is changed etc using standard SharePoint task list

[image]

When it sends the email to people the default "ID" number sharepoint autogenerates does not appear on the email, is it possible to add this in?

I saw some ideas about creating a column called e.g. #ID and set it equal to [ID] but is there anything more user friendly to help show the ID number when an email is sent?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to modify the email template. But the title link contains ID parameter, you may have a look.

[image]

The behind URL is:

```
https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/s01/Lists/testask/Dispform.aspx?ID=2
```

You can get the id from above url.

BR